# Transparent gifs shows background colour on Android devices

Tags: jquery, android, gif

I have a web page where I animate some of the elements (transparent GIFs) with jQuery.
It works fine on all browsers desktop and mobile. I have noticed though that on Android devices the GIFs show a weird colour as background, similar to the IE bug with alpha channel for PNGs.
After the page has loaded the first time, if I refresh it the weird background doesn't show.
Any idea anyone?

Thanks
Mauro